# Avoiding the duplicate selection of names in the dom using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please look into the the attached jsfiddle .

My expected output is to

1) Assign selected boy to the selected boy column.

2) Avoid duplicate selection because i may already have selected boy when the page loads. So objective should be .

Techincal Issue 
1) whenever the dropdpwn changes look at all the other dropdown selected options  and also look at the SELCTED BOY column top see whether we already have that boy selected.;

MY  FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/bharatgillala/pnzh255v/6/

```
<TABLE id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation class=mGrid style="WIDTH:   750px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" cellSpacing=0 border=0><TBODY>
<TR>
<TH scope=col>Room #</TH>
 <TH scope=col> BoyName</TH>
 <TH scope=col>Selected Boy</TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD style="WIDTH: 30px" align=left>1</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 60px" align=left><SPAN     id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl02_lblAvailableHE>Eleanor </SPAN>     <INPUT id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl02_HDN_ROOM_ID type=hidden     value=8 name=ctl00$contentBody$gvRoomAllocation$ctl02$HDN_ROOM_ID> </TD>
   <TD style="WIDTH: 60px" align=left><SELECT id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl02_ddlAvailableJudges class=judges   name=ctl00$contentBody$gvRoomAllocation$ctl02$ddlAvailableJudges> <OPTION   selected value=-1></OPTION> <OPTION value="Eleanor">Eleanor</OPTION> <OPTION value="Patricia">Patricia </OPTION> <OPTION   value="Pantaleoni">Pantaleoni</OPTION> <OPTION value="Dianne">Dianne </OPTION>      </SELECT> </TD></TR>
 <TR class=alt>
<TD style="WIDTH: 30px" align=left>2</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 50px" align=left><SPAN    id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl03_lblAvailableHE></SPAN><INPUT id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl03_HDN_ROOM_ID type=hidden value=9  name=ctl00$contentBody$gvRoomAllocation$ctl03$HDN_ROOM_ID> </TD>
  <TD style="WIDTH: 95px" align=left><SELECT      id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl03_ddlAvailableJudges class=judges name=ctl00$contentBody$gvRoomAllocation$ctl03$ddlAvailableJudges> <OPTION      selected value=-1></OPTION> <OPTION value="Eleanor , Rand"> Eleanor</OPTION>    <OPTION value="Patricia , Cardoso">Patricia </OPTION> <OPTION value="David ,     Pantaleoni">Pantaleoni</OPTION> <OPTION value="Dianne , Malone">Dianne </OPTION>      </SELECT> </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD style="WIDTH: 90px" align=left>3</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 140px" align=left><SPAN      id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl04_lblAvailableHE>Patricia </SPAN> <INPUT id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl04_HDN_ROOM_ID type=hidden    value=10 name=ctl00$contentBody$gvRoomAllocation$ctl04$HDN_ROOM_ID> </TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 95px" align=left><SELECT   id=ctl00_contentBody_gvRoomAllocation_ctl04_ddlAvailableJudges class=judges   name=ctl00$contentBody$gvRoomAllocation$ctl04$ddlAvailableJudges> <OPTION  selected value=-1></OPTION> <OPTION value="Eleanor , Rand">Eleanor</OPTION>     <OPTION value="Patricia , Cardoso">Patricia </OPTION> <OPTION value="David ,  Pantaleoni">David</OPTION> <OPTION value="Dianne , Malone">Dianne </OPTION>         </SELECT> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Comment: And where are the dropdowns? There isn't any in fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the span above the select is the where the value goes, I think this is what you need

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.closest('span').text($el.val());
});
```